# Jupyter notebook is giving error when using MinMaxScalar or StandardScalar?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When performing StandardScalar or MinMaxScalar using PythonAdv kernel the jupyter notebook is printing error. However, when using Python 3 environment the same jupyter note book is working fine:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Scale X values
X_scalar = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
#print(X_scalar)
X_train_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e5dc00a586d3> in <module>
      4 X_scalar = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
      5 #print(X_scalar)
----> 6 X_train_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_train)
      7 X_test_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_test)

NameError: name 'X_scaler' is not defined
```

I have Anaconda 3, python 3.6 and PythonAdv environments on Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: You have a typo; it should be `X_scalar`, not `X_scaler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Scale X values
X_scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
#print(X_scalar)
X_train_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_test)
```

There is a small typo. you define X_scalar then use X_scaler.